# JSlider Middle label cant go over 3 characters

Tags: java, swing, jlabel, jslider

I have a `JSlider` and have 3 labels in my label table, one for 0 one for 50 and one for 100. Now in my `ChangeListener` state Changed I set the middle label. It works for all he numbers other then 100. Then for some reason it displays ... instead of 100:

```
    Hashtable<Integer, JLabel> labelTable = new Hashtable<Integer, JLabel>();
    final JLabel middleLabel = new JLabel("50");
    labelTable.put(0, new JLabel("0"));
    labelTable.put(50, middleLabel);
    labelTable.put(100, new JLabel("100"));
    final JSlider slider = new JSlider(0, 100, 50);
    slider.addChangeListener(new ChangeListener()
    {
      @Override
      public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent e)
      {
        middleLabel.setText("" + slider.getValue());
      }
    });
    slider.setLabelTable(labelTable);
    slider.setPaintLabels(true);
```

[image]

Question is that is there any way i can display the 100 instead of the ... what it is currently displaying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that the middle label is too small to display "100" because it was initially created with the narrower text "50", and JSlider doesn't act as a container which resizes its children as their preferred size changes, it just lays out the labels once.

Try initialising the label with "100" instead of "50".

Comment: Also, and this is just a personal thing, i despise the `"" + number` way of turning a number into a string. It's ugly and doesn't say what you want to do. It's also inefficient, since it requires creating a StringBuilder, appending two strings to it and invoking toString() to get the actual result.

Just use `Integer.toString(slider.getValue())` instead.

Comment: Thanks set it to 100 and it worked. It now shows the number perfectly thanks allot mate. Also thanks for the Integer.tostring(int i) tip did not think of it that it had to create a string builder just cause of that.